# How to write additional CSS in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, css, magento-2.1.3

Where can I add additional CSS in Magento 2 which will not be removed by upgrades?

Answer (score 2):

You need to add your styling in the LESS files (default M2 anyway), and then compile them. You can read how to compile LESS on the official dev docs [here](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/css-topics/css-preprocess.html).

The LESS files can be found inside your theme, for example:

```
<your_theme>/<module>/web/css/_extend.less
```

Answer (score 2):

You can either add a separate CSS file for your style or you can write in the existing CSS theme.less file.

> app/design/frontend/Vendorname/Themename/web/css/souce/theme.less